# Is this memoy-usage optimization technique ever possible in case of unions?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory, compiler-construction, unions

In case of Union objects, may a compiler be smart enough to detect at which points what amount of union's memory is used so that the rest memory of union can be used for other purposes as an memory-usage optimization or this is not even allowed due to how standard defines union?

Answer (score 1):

No.

To do that, the compiler would have to know what you are "using" at any given time. How could it possible do that? What if *you* were using the "unused" section for your own optimisations?

Comment: You are allowed only to read the last written member.  A compiler can do whatever it wants with the remainder.  A practical use on an architecture able only to write full words not to take care to keep out the other bytes when writing a byte sized members of a larger union.

Answer (score 1):

A union reserves space sufficient to store the largest of its members<sup>1</sup>. So, by definition, the same space is reserved for `union { double a;  byte b }` whether you happen to have stored through the double or the byte.

Try not to think of a union as a variant type that can be *either* a byte or a double or an int depending on which member you happened to write most recently. It is in fact a mechanism for overlaying multiple different data types on the same region of memory, so that region is *simultaneously* a float and an int and a what-have-you in a sort of quantum superimposition. This is especially useful for [type-punning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) which is when you need to get around the language's type system.

<sup>1</sup>ANSI/ISO 9899.

Comment: My understanding is that we should think of unions as a variant type and only the member which has been written the more recently can be read and type punning with union is undefined behavior. (The special rules allowing to inspect the common prefix of structures in an union would be without object if it wasn't the case.  I'm pretty sure I've already read better references in the standard than that but I can't find them now.)

Comment: Well, subverting the type system is always undefined behavior, but it's also sometimes just plain necessary when you are trying to do some platform specific things (like fiddling the sign bits of floats). One of the changes from C90 to C99 was to remove any restriction on accessing one member of a union when the last store was to a different one. Embedded programmers often have to do things that make language purists scream.

Comment: There is a difference between C++ and C here and I answered in the context of C++.  First what is common: in both cases assigning to a member makes the bytes unused by this member undefined (it is very clear in C, 6.2.6.1/7 in N1124) and I think the compiler can assume that what it wrote is still there (but I didn't find a statement as clear).  What isn't common, in C reading another member than the last written was implementation defined and now got somewhat defined.  As far as I know, in C++ it is undefined (at least I didn't find anything hinting otherwise, I'm interested if you know some).

Comment: @Crashworks: the guarantee in C99 only says that the current value of the union (i.e. the last-written value) is reinterpreted, it doesn't say what happens to prior values of the union. So for instance in a `union { char c; char ca[4]; }`, if you write `ca[2]`, then write `c`, I don't think it's *guaranteed* that you can then read back `ca[2]` and get the value you set for that, whereas you can read `ca[0]` and get the value of `c` you set. You might be a bit upset with your compiler vendor, but I *think* it's conforming behavior.

Comment: @Steve, 6.2.6.1/7 is very clear you can't expect c[1] to keep its value and on an architecture where you can't write a single byte, I expect you won't see it happen.

Comment: @AProgrammer: nice one, thanks. Even so, some implementations provide enhanced guarantees, I think.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: They do. In particular, one thing thing that MSVC, GCC, SN, and MW all mercifully provide is that in `union {float f; int i;} u; u.f = 1.0f; return u.i;`, u.i actually gets the bit pattern that I just stored through f. That is to say, this forces the compiler to commit the write from float register so that it can be read onto the int pipe, because of the implicit dependency. I think I might be sending flaming arrows to my compiler vendors otherwise.

Comment: @Crashworks: you *could* do `float f = 1.0; int i; memcpy(&i,&f,sizeof(i)); return i;` instead. On GCC, it'll optimize to the same thing: put the float bit pattern straight into whatever the calling convention says is the return register/stack slot. So if I shoot flaming arrows at compiler vendors who can't make that optimization, we might make some progress. Assuming `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`, though, your pun is totally legal in C99, so C++ compilers which are also C99 compilers are going to support it in C++ too, you'd expect.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I guess I could also just do `float f = 1.0f; return *reinterpret_cast<int *>(&f);` but the case where I actually need to do this in practice involves casting from a pointer-to-function to a pointer-to-object. That is both forbidden by ISO C++ and completely necessary in our app (to get around some problems with the PowerPC ABI and dynamic linkage).

Comment: @Crashworks: That reinterpret_cast is more likely to fail with strict aliasing. I'm pretty sure it actually does fail on GCC: with enough optimization the initialization of `f` will be elided as an unused value, and you'll return garbage. In your case where you're doing something deeply unpleasant because of a specific ABI, I'm entirely unfussed what hack is needed, since you aren't writing portable code anyway. If some particular compiler for PowerPC didn't support the union pun, you could drop in some assembler or whatever it takes to get that compiler working. And also shoot flaming arrows.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I've just found such a compiler. I hope my flaming arrows reach Japan.

Comment: DVd: Type-punning through a `union` is undefined behaviour in C++. Your answer specifically touts the fact that it _happens to work_ on A Compiler as a distinct advantage, which is a very misleading impression to give to readers in the main. Sure, you rely on it, and it works for you, which is great - but IMO your post should at least warn that it's completely non-portable.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think how.

It can't use the extra space for a different object, because objects don't overlap in memory unless one is a subobject of the other.

Also, it can't use the extra space at all if you could come along and write the largest member of the union at any second.

In code like this:

```
{
    union { char c; double d; } x;
    x.c = 1;
    int y;
    some_function(&y);
    std::cout << x.c;
}
```

I suppose that under the "as-if" rule, the compiler could reduce the stack used for `x` down to 1 byte, and use the memory immediately after that for `y`. Since the address of `x` is never taken, there is no way for a conforming program to "observe" the difference, so it's valid.

Not sure if that's the kind of thing you meant, though, since the use of this union `x` is surrounded with a lot of restrictions to make that valid. This isn't so much a case of detecting at what points in time the remainder of the union is unused, as detecting that at all points, the remainder is unused.

You might think that the same optimization could apply here:

```
{
    union { char c; double d; } x;
    x.c = 1;
    int y;
    some_function(&y);
    std::cout << x.c;
    x.d = 1.0;
    std::cout << x.d;
}
```

but what if `some_function` were to retain a copy of the pointer to `y`, perhaps in a global? Then if the overloaded `operator<<` might end up indirectly calling any code that uses that pointer, it's not valid for the compiler to have overwritten the memory. I doubt that any implementation can fully inline `std::cout << x.d`, so even if that doesn't happen, the compiler isn't going to know that it doesn't, and can't make the optimization.

For a really huge union, spanning multiple pages of RAM, I think that in theory the physical RAM for the later pages could be released when a small union member is written, and re-mapped back in on demand. Hardly seems worth the implementation bothering with, though, considering that's going to be a very rare case, and not much better than ordinary use of a swap file.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, this is possible. If the compiler is smart enough to analyze your program and finds out that you never ever use the biggest type it can hold, it could optimize the program under the as-if rule. (The program's behavior - except for timing - must be as if the optimization hadn't taken place.)

But it's unlikely that a compiler would do this. It's hard to do so and it's rarely ever applicable.

Answer (score 0):

No, a union is aligned according to the alignment requirements of its largest member.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. The compiler has no way to know at any given time how much space is being used. However, there is no reason to use a union in C++, as it only accepts POD types (slightly less restricted in C++0x), and with the boost::variant and boost::any types around, there's no need for such a language feature.

Comment: It's still necessary if you need to overlay two unrelated structures in the same region of memory so you can poke at them in platform-specific ways. For example, `union funcdescriptor {uint64 i; void(*fptr)(); struct{ void *toc; void *codeaddress; };};` is probably the easiest way to fish the TOC and IP sections individually out of a function pointer (which is actually a pointer to a descriptor, and so on) when you're working with the PowerPC ABI.